# Unable to install any packages on Kali

Tags: linux, kali-linux, apt

Windows admin, Linux newbie trying to do some really basic stuff for a class I'm taking. I'm using the official VMWare appliance from Kali so I would think everything is configured to a point of basic functionality, but when I type apt install ccrypt it all goes to hell.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ccrypt

It connects to the internet so NAT is working. I switched over to root and that didn't help. Running apt update or apt-get update come back with 111 connection refused. I confirmed the information in /etc/apt/sources.list is what it should be. After running sudo apt update and sudo apt full-upgrade -y it gives me

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontent lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

sudo apt install ccrypt returns an infinite infinite loop of:
Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend.

When I did it in the premade online VM within the course I entered the command and it just worked like it was supposed to. I have no idea what the issue is with a clean install. Please help.

Comment: did you do a `sudo apt update` followed by a `sudo apt full-upgrade -y` ?  You might try this first, then try again.  Please update your post rather than replying in comments. :)

Comment: *apt-get update come back with 111 connection refused* suggest there's something wrong with the interne access, indeed. Or that you're behind a proxy. The 2nd error error "could not open lock..." is unrelated and simply means there's something else already running, possibly updating already in the background. So, wait a few minutes to try again or reboot.

Comment: Try building a Kali machine in VMware Workstation. That works fine. I am posting from Kali here.